# How to execute test using tasks in nightwatch?

Tags: automated-tests, task, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to execute a group of tests. I see at nightwatch documentation about group and tasks and I'm using tasks to run specifics tests. The problem is that nightwatch recognizes the test but does not execute it.

nightwatch return:
[image: nightwatch return]

```
Starting selenium server in parallel mode... started - PID:  1404

If you want to upload Screenshots to S3
      please set your AWS Environment Variables (see readme).
Started child process for: adquirentes\antecipacao

  >> adquirentes\antecipacao finished.
```

As you can see, the test was started but not executed. How can I fix it?

Comment: You should put the results you get in the body of the question. Link-rot means that this question becomes less useful for others in the future.

Comment: Sry.. added.. that was i got in return.